# Close any TabControl TabPage when middle clicked on

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, mouseclick-event

I want to be able to middle click the tab on a `TabPage` and have it removed from the `TabControl` but even with HotTracking turned on, I don't know how to capture which tab I middle clicked on.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Sorry, yes, it's a `WinForms` application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this on the `MouseClick` event of your `TabControl`:

```
private void tabControl_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Middle)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < tabControl.TabCount; i++)
        {
            if (tabControl.GetTabRect(i).Contains(e.Location))
            {
                tabPaControl.TabPages[i].Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```